# Use GP for Solving Symbolic Regression

Tags: genetic-programming

I understand how to solve a simple symbolic regression problem such as f(x)=x4+x3+x2+x. However, I'm not quite sure how to use GP to solve the below one.

f(x) = x2 + cosx + 7, for x<=0,
       1/x + 2x, for x>0

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It says that you compare against

```
f = x<=0 ? x2 + cosx + 7 : 1/x + 2x
```

instead of

```
f = x4+x3+x2+x
```